# How do I use SpringFuse?

Tags: java, frameworks

I go there http://www.springfuse.com/ I don't even understand what's the purpose of filling their quick form start there's not even a submit button :(

Is it a generator online, is it a software to download, what is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no downloads. It generates Maven commands. As it says:

1. To generate a project, adjust the settings below and execute the resulting command lines in a console.
2. Once you are done, copy-paste these maven commands lines in a console..
3. Then once all is ready you can open your browser and go to http://localhost:8080/myproject

[This explains](http://www.springfuse.com/what-is-springfuse.html) SpringFuse a bit clearer.

Comment: ok thanks but as I said I can't even see a submit button how do I validate :)

Comment: Every time you change the form the generated Maven commands will change as well. When you're satisfied with the configuration you copy the commands to a console and execute them. :)

Answer (score 2):

That form helps you to generate the maven command and you have to install [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to execute that command.

Once you execute that generated command using Maven and Maven will create a folder containing the source code of a web application that is built using the technologies you choose in the form as well as help you to download the necessary jar .You can then import the generated project to your IDE to develop.

It probably  something likes [Appfuse2](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) , which will create a web application which has some basic functions such as user login , CRUD page to do user management , user signup and registration etc for you . It then eliminating the ramp-up time that is spent to build the infrastructure code , and the basic application function when building a new web application.  Meanwhile , it claims that the generated project is world-class that follows the best practices of your chosen frameworks.

---

**Reference**

[Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)